# How to access formState.errors when using FormProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm building an abstract "deeply-nested" form component that uses `FormProvider`. I have error validation working at the `field` level, but I can't figure out how to access the `errors` object at the `formState` level.

The `FormProvider` [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext) say that "FormProvider requires all useForm methods," and the example code goes

```
export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
    ...
```

My (seemingly working) abstract form component looks like this:

```
let renderCount = 0;

function FormDialog(props) {
  const {
    open, onClose, loading, headline, noEscape, onFormSubmit, content, actions
  } = props;

  renderCount++;

  let validationSchema = YupObject().shape({});

  // construct schema
  content.forEach(item => {
    validationSchema = validationSchema.concat(YupObject().shape({
      [item.component.props.name]: item.validation
    }));
  });

  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      disableEscapeKeyDown={loading || noEscape}
    >
      <DialogTitle>{headline}</DialogTitle>
      <Box>
        Render Count: {renderCount}
      </Box>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <DialogContent>
          <Box component="form" 
            sx={{
              onSubmit: methods.handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)
            }}
          >
            <FormContent content={content} />
          </Box>
          <HighlightedInformation>
          </HighlightedInformation>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <FormActions actions={actions} />
        </DialogActions>
      </FormProvider>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default FormDialog;
```

Like that, it renders, displays "Render Count: 2" (because I'm in dev mode, therefore using `React.StrictMode`) and nicely points out errors at the `field` level. However, I can't figure out how to access the `formState` `errors` property.

All of the examples I can find pull the `formState` out during the initial `useForm` call:

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState
  } = useForm();
```

However, I need to pull *all* of the `methods` out because of the `FormProvider`. It doesn't seem a good idea to explicitly restructure them all. Various things I've tried:

**useFormState():**

```
  ...
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });
  
  const { errors } = useFormState();
  console.log('errors', errors);
  ...
```

**explicitly pass `control`**

```
  const { errors } = useFormState( methods.control );
  console.log('errors', errors);
```

both result in `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'methods.control')`.

**Destructure `methods` to get to the object**:

```
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  const { formState: {errors} } = methods;
  console.log('errors', errors);
```

**Wrap in useEffect** as described in the `formState` [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate#main):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('errors:', methods.formState.errors);
  },[methods.formState]);
```

Both of the latter two result in infinite re-renders and the browser hanging.

So, how do I get to `formState` `errors` when using `FormProvider` and pulling out all of the `methods`?

Comment: Where exactly you need `formState`? In the same component where you initialise `useForm`?

Comment: Yes. (I'm actually trying to diagnose why my `onSubmit` isn't working, and in another question here, the suggestion was to look at `formState` errors — and I can't get that to work :) )

Comment: So why exactly just destructuring does not work for you? What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Destructuring ... where? As I mentioned in the question, the two attempts I made at it resulted in infinite re-renders and the browser hanging.

Comment: Just destructure like that `const { formState: {errors} } = methods` and use it, no need for `useEffect`. You do realise that `App` `useForm` is completely different form from your `FormDialog ` `useForm`? They not connected in any way, `FormProvider` does nothing in your case. Would be much better if you could provide some reproducible example on https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Yes, the `App` code was literally from the example docs I was quoting; it's not in my code at all. Maybe my exposition wasn't clear enough, but my `const { formState: {errors} } = methods` and `useEffect` were two different examples; they just both result in the infinite loops. I'll try and get something up on codesandbox.

Comment: OK, something up here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-lehmann-semsv. Uncomment the section marked, and watch the browser hang. :( It's simplified from my code, but shows the problem.

Comment: I can't see any marked section to uncomment, you sure it's there? But I can see that you are incorrectly using `Controller`, you need to pass control prop there. And `ConnectForm` basically does nothing now

Comment: Huh. I must have deleted it when recovering from when I double checked that it broke things. It's there now. re: `Controller`, the docs say "control object is from invoking useForm. Optional when using FormProvider." I'm happy to put it back, but I think that part is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a few things and it seems to work now: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70936454-w2py3?file=/src/App.js)

1. Don't pass `onSubmit` as `sx` prop. I think sx is supposed to only accept style props, not sure why it allows callbacks and etc.
2. Wrap `form` element around submit button, otherwise you won't be able to submit it.
3. `ConnectForm` was doing nothing so I removed it too, but not sure if it has any effect on the bug.